# Getting defaultValue from form React

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to edit element item from list, i get data to the form as defaultValue, when i need some changes it chages but inputs which is not changed sets as empty when i submit form. how Can i get these values ? [image]

[image]

Comment: please add your code snippets

Comment: How are you passing the values in the code? We can help you if you share the code.